# What does ntdll_77bc0000 or ntdll_772d0000 means in Wow64 call stack

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have WOW64 crash dumps with call stack information like:

```
0018fb00 77c06a8b 0018fbc8 0018ffc4 0018fc18 ntdll_77bc0000!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
```

or like:

```
0018fb00 77c06a8b 0018fbc8 0018ffc4 0018fc18 ntdll_772d0000!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
```

The ntdll_772d0000 seems to be a dll name, but I didn't see it in C:\Windows\SysWOW64, and I am also curious why there might be different names like ntdll_77bc0000 and ntdll_772d0000 on the same machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these are multiple copies of ntdll loaded at alternate (as opposed to preferred) base addresses.

Comment: I didn't see these dlls in my system, do you mean these are all temporary dlls that generated in runtime for a certain process? Is there any materials I can refer to?

Comment: This is a single dll loaded multiple times into your process(es). Weird thing is it's ntdll. Can you post more of the stack? Also, run list modules (lm) to see how many copies you have and maybe spot differences between them (look at version info, etc)